# Infinite loops for turtle listen

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am running into an infinite loop in this code. It should break out if you click in the desired range, however it goes into an infinite loop displaying the current position of the turtle in the row and column format.

```
def wait_for_click():
    turt.penup()
    wn.onclick(turt.goto)
    wn.listen()
    pos = [-1,-1]
    row = -1
    column = -1
    while row > 8 or row < 0  or column > 8 or column < 0:
        row = ((turt.ycor()-turt.ycor()%75)+75)/75 + 4
        column = ((turt.xcor()-turt.xcor()%75)+75)/75 + 4
    pos[0] = row
    pos[1] = column
    print(pos)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your basic approach is wrong: don't loop waiting for the turtle to show up somewhere interesting, instead use the click handler to test where the turtle showed up:

```
from math import ceil
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

CELLS = 8
CELL_SIZE = 75
STAMP_SIZE = 20

def click_handler(x, y):
    screen.onclick(None)

    yertle.goto(x, y)

    if 0 < x < CELLS and 0 < y < CELLS:
        position = [ceil(x), ceil(y)]
        print(position)

    screen.onclick(click_handler)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(CELL_SIZE * (CELLS + 2), CELL_SIZE * (CELLS + 2))
screen.setworldcoordinates(-1, -1, CELLS + 1, CELLS + 1)

screen.onclick(click_handler)

marker = Turtle(shape="square")
marker.penup()
marker.turtlesize(CELL_SIZE / STAMP_SIZE)
marker.color("gray", "white")

for x in range(0, CELLS):
    for y in range(0, CELLS):
        marker.goto(x + 0.5, y + 0.5)
        marker.stamp()
        marker.color(*marker.color()[::-1])
    marker.color(*marker.color()[::-1])

yertle = Turtle(shape="circle")
yertle.speed("fastest")
yertle.penup()

screen.mainloop()
```

I've thrown in code to show the grid so you can see that where you click matches the printed output.  I used `setworldcoordinates()` to simplify the problem with the side effect that I've given you a larger border.

The lower left cell is [1, 1] and the upper right is [8, 8] -- you may want to do some math to switch these around.